# About marriage in islamic shariah

Tags: nikah

If husband of a wife involved with another woman for couple of years,will their marriage annul in islamic shariah?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: What do you mean? Elaborate! Whom's marriage would annul and why? And what do you mean by "husband involved with another woman"?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum brother, 
I hope you're doing well.

The case you mentioned in your question in this case their marriage will not be annul but the husband is committing great sin that is (کبیرۃ) which cannot be forgiven without (توبۃ). And if he dies without توبۃ his sin will remain their and can cause him goin to hell.

توبۃ means asking forgiveness from Allah clean hearted and being ashamed of what he has done and not repeating it again ever.

I hope I answered the question.
Thank you.